# Update Query Will Not Work Due To Key Violations

Tags: sql-update, ms-access-2010

I am trying to update a specific field in the "Claims" table of my 2010 Access Database. I keep receiving an error message that says there are key violations. Here is the SQL:

UPDATE Claims SET Claims.LS_Name = "JPN"
WHERE (((Claims.Responsibility2)=0));

Is there any reason, based on the above code, that it is not working?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

My first guess would be that there is a unique key on **Claims.LS_Name** and your update hits more than one row.

Comment: There is a unique index, that is the primary key in that table, do I need to temporarily remove the pk?

Comment: After you have the same value in multiple rows, you could not add the pk again. A primary key is always unique and not null, therefore the same value in different rows is not allowed.

Comment: I think there is a flaw in your database model. A pk column is always used to identify a single row in a table (unique and not null). Therefore the pk does not belong to ls_name. But I have not enough info about your datamodel to suggest something more concrete.

Comment: I'm certain that there are design flaws, unfortunately, I did not design it but I have to keep developing it, because my pleas have fallen upon deaf ears. I will keep thinking about it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I ran into this issue as well in Microsoft Access and think I have ways to solve versions of this.  The intermediate table may not be necessary.  My experience is that autonumber is the issue so conversion to number seems to work, but you have to delete relationships for Access to allow this change.

1. remove all relationships to the destination table.
2. change from autonumber to number.
3. make new empty tablethatincrements starting with the next higher key https://superuser.com/questions/288087/how-do-i-set-the-first-value-of-autonumber-in-access
4. update/query to the tablethatincrements table instead of destination.
5. update/merge from tablethatincrementsto to the destination table, including new higher keys.
6. remake relationships

OR In certain situations. (for mine the new keys matched the old)
something like this (may not be exact steps)

1. remove all relationships to the destination table.
2. delete ID/primary key in destination
3. merge/update to destination
4. create new ID/Primary key in destination (so it can be autonumber to renumber keys)
5. remake relationships

Anyway my next research item is to see how to never use autoincrement and do the unique keys using other methods so relationships do not have to be removed to change from autoincrement to number.